# Avg difference between consecutive mysql rows for specific month

Tags: mysql, average, difference

I'm busy creating a personal mobile web app for home management.

Each day a READING is entered into a table, along with the days DATE.
One reading per day, meaning DATE is unique. READING could be the same, by very unlikely, if there is no usage for that day.

A usage amount for the day is calculated, by subtracting the previous days reading from the newly input reading.

How would I calculate the average usage numbers for a particular month?
Should the usage amount, once calculated, perhaps be stored back to the newly added row? Leaving for easy use of this to find an average?
Should a separate primary key be added, numbering the records, as apposed to using date to calculate the latest record added?

Thank you in advance, any help appreciated

Comment: Calculate the usage when a new reading is entered and just calculate the average of usage for that month using the avg() function.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:
When adding the latest readings, calculate day usage using previous record (found by using date). Add this to a third column.

To find daily average for current month, use MySQL avg, and limit to current year, and current month.

Comment: Well, it's not what I'd do

Comment: @Strawberry: would you mind sharing how?
This is a very small, once a day usage, app. So while not needing to be super optimised, a chance to see another solution, or a better one, is always welcome.